# Java type safe equals()

Tags: java, equals, type-safety

Why is there no type-safe `equals()` in Java? I would think that would help catching some errors during compile time instead of later runtime error.

As a trivial example consider this:

```
class Person {
    Integer birthYear;
} 

class Car {
    Long releaseYear;
}
```

Having a method to take in a Person and collection of Cars and suppose to list all the Cars released in the same year the person was born could end up using:

```
if (person.birthYear.equals(car.releaseYear)) {
...magic happens...
}
```

But no magic would ever happen using this. Even if the fields are of same type during the creation of the code, either could be changed at a later point without getting compile error on the comparison code.

What would be best practice to avoid these sort of problems?

Comment: Because Java's type system is not rich enough to make that actually possible.

Comment: Tools like FindBugs can warn about calling equals on types that can't be equal.

Comment: this was covered also there: http://rickyclarkson.blogspot.si/2006/12/making-equalsobject-type-safe.html

Answer (score 3):

By design, Java's `equals()` method takes an `Object` so that you can make a heterogeneous collection of objects and compare them against each other for equality.

For example, you might have a list of arbitrary objects:

```
List<Object> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add("abc");
lst.add(123);  // Integer
lst.add(456L);  // Long
```

Then the fact that `equals()` takes an `Object` means you can implement:

```
void indexOf(List<Object> lst, Object target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        if (lst.get(i).equals(target))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

To answer your concern specifically, the only way to be "type-safe" is to define a new method name like `strictEquals()`, and only implement the parameter with your type, not the `Object` type. For example:

```
class Person {
    boolean strictEquals(Person other) { ... }
}

class Car {
    boolean strictEquals(Car other) { ... }
}
```

---

Regarding your use of `Integer` and `Long` as fields, **don't do that**. Use the primitive types `int` and `long` instead, and use the `==` operator to compare values. This has a number of advantages, like better performance, no `NullPointerException`, and the ability to compare `int` to `long` properly (whereas `Integer.equals(Long)` will always return false due to different types, even if the objects have the same numerical value).